# How can I get the auto-generated id when a record is created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When record is created, it has an auto-generated id. I want to get it.

I created a table of names in Ruby On Rails.

I entered four names:

- Alon
- Bil
- Hilary
- Erez

In my table, there is an auto id, right? The name 'Alon' is assigned id=1, and so on - the name 'Erez' with id=4. this Id is not an id that I defined in my table.

I explain with another words:

When I enter the function 'Show' for the name 'Alon', it looks like: `http://localhost:3000/mycontroller/1`. (I think that '1' is the id of where the name 'Alon' is found in my table.

**How can I get this id?**

```
def index
   @name = Tablenames.find(:all, :conditions => ["name=?", "Alon"]);
end
```

`index.html.erb`:

```
<% @name.each do |worker_name| %> worker_name.id <% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When do you need the ID? Directly after creation?

```
user = User.create(name: "Alon")

puts user.id
```

When you're searching for the name?

```
user = User.find_by_name "Alon"

puts user.id
```

Comment: In my controller, I defined: @name = Tablenames.find(:all, :conditions => ["name=?", "Alon"]);

Comment: in index.html.erb: <% @name.each do |worker_name| %> worker_name.id <% end %> it doesn't let me the id of Alon. there is no column with the parameter: "id".

Comment: can you add your corresponding migration file to you question? also: did you write `worker_name` or `worker name`in the view? can't see it exactly.

Comment: can you insert index action code in question and also part of view where you are trying to print id?

Comment: I updated my code.. I have to say that I don't have this id in my columns of the table.

Comment: okay, lets try something simple: please go to your app directory and start `rails c`. Then type: `Tablenames.first`. You'll get a response. Write it exactly here down please.

Comment: You need to learn more basic Rails fundamentals, user1961415. Try something like the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/).

Comment: uvote @SunnyJuneja, i highly recommend it too. Naming Coventions would also be important after understanding how everything works.